# python, django, display the correct field name by FK, linked tables

Tags: python, django

models.py file

```
#create class roles, id, portal_name, role_name
class Roles(models.Model):
    portal_name = models.CharField(_('Portal name'), max_length=100)
    role_name = models.CharField(_('Role_name'), max_length=50)


#create permission for roles
class RolePermission(models.Model):
    module_name = models.CharField(_('Module name'), max_length=100)
    module_delete = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="Delete module. Default false, can't delete")
    module_edit = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="Edit module. Default false, can't edit")
    module_create = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="Create module. Default false, can't create")
    module_submit = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="Submit module, Default false.")
    module_role_id = models.ForeignKey('Roles', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

[image]

[image]

my admin.py file

```
@admin.register(RolePermission)
class RolePermissionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('module_name', 'module_role_id_id', 'module_delete', 'module_edit', 'module_create', 'module_submit')
```

as in the column display information on role_name from table roles, used Foreign Key

Comment: Please share the `ModelAdmin`.

Comment: added information to the question (updated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a method, and use the name of that method in the `list_display`. For this specific case we thus the `role_name` of the related `.module_role_id`:

```
@admin.register(RolePermission)
class RolePermissionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('module_name', 'role_name', 'module_delete', 'module_edit', 'module_create', 'module_submit')

    @admin.display(description='role name')
    def role_name(self, obj):
        return obj.module_role_id.role_name
```

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `module_role`, instead of <s>`module_role_id`</s>.

Answer (score 2):

you can make new property and use it in list_display,
it should be like this :

```
class RolePermission(models.Model):
    module_name = models.CharField(_('Module name'), max_length=100)
    module_delete = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="Delete module. Default false, can't delete")
    module_edit = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="Edit module. Default false, can't edit")
    module_create = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="Create module. Default false, can't create")
    module_submit = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="Submit module, Default false.")
    module_role_id = models.ForeignKey('Roles', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def  module_role(self):
        return self.module_role_id.role_name
```

and your list_display should be like this:

```
    list_display = ('module_name', 'module_role', 'module_delete', 'module_edit', 'module_create', 'module_submit')
```